# Rails model update doen't work after cap migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, capistrano, rails-migrations

I have a Rails 3.2 application and I have some issues on the production side:

I have a model 'Poject' and did a migration to add a string for 'description'.
running 
`rake db:migrate`
works fine on my developer machine like all the times.
But when I do a `cap deploy` and `cap migrate` on the production server I cannot update my
project models which where already in the database. Only new ones work fine.
I'm using postgres 9.1

I don't know what's the issue here since its working fine on my local machine.

Regards

Oliver

Comment: Have you restarted the rails server? Probably it'll fix this issue

Comment: Did you also add a presence validation for the `description`? Fire up a console on your production server, try to update an existing project  and if it fails take a look at `project.errors`.

Comment: @techvineet Yes I did... And its working fine when I create a new Project model.

Comment: what does `project.errors` give you after you attempt to update in the console?

Comment: yes I did a presence validation. firing up the console give me this error: database configuration does not specify adapter. do I need to define a development mode in production?

Comment: @user2258116: when starting up in production - you need to use the 'production' mode - something like this should work for you: `bundle exec rails c production`

Comment: copy and paste you database.yml here.

Comment: It looks like the validation was the problem:
validating the presence of a newly added field creates the problem for the existing records.

thanks.

Comment: @PinnyM: bundle exec rails c production works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I did run the `cap deploy:migrate` task. But here the problem was that I was validating the existence of a newly created field and this caused the trouble with the records which where already in the database.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `cap deploy:migrate`.

```
Run the migrate rake task. By default, it runs this in most recently deployed
version of the app...
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks

Also make sure you are using the right environment while using capistrano